# Proof for continuity of $h(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ -x, & x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I have the given function and I have to find out, where it is continuous and discontinuous...

My guess is, that the function is discontinuous on all $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$ and continuous in $0$. Could you look over my proof and give me a feedback?

**Proof:**

For $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ look at the sequence $(q_n)$, which converges to $x$. The sequence $(h(q_n))$ is then equal to the sequence $(q_n)$ and therefore converges to $x$, so we can conclude: $\lim_{n->\infty}h(q_n))=h(\lim_{n->\infty}q_n)=h(x)=x$

For $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$ look at the sequence $(r_n)$, which converges to $x$. The sequence $(h(r_n))$ is then equal to the sequence $-(r_n)$ and therefore converges to $-x$, so we can conclude: $\lim_{n->\infty}h(r_n))=x\neq-x=h(\lim_{n->\infty}-r_n)$

Therefore $h$ can't be continuous (I don't know the exact theorem name, but the subsequences of a function has to have the limit $h(x_0)$, if $h(x)$ is continuous in $x_0$

So the function is only continuous in $x=0$. Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta =\epsilon$, then we have:
$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R} : |x-x_0|=|x-0|<\delta =\epsilon \Rightarrow |h(x)-h(x_0)|=|h(x)-x_0|=|h(x)|=|x|<\epsilon$

We can conclude, that the function is continuous in 0 and discontinuous for every $\mathbb{R} \setminus 0$

Comment: Your guess is correct. The proof for continuity in $0$ is also good, but you can omit the "$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$", because you already chose an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and $\delta=\epsilon$. The proof of discontinuity in any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is not quite correct. If you pick a sequence $x_n \to x$, the $x_n$ could be both rational or irrational numbers. You should try to pick a specific sequence $x_n \to x$ such that $h(x_n) \to x$ is not true.

Comment: By specific you mean something like $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ (just an example, not a valid sequence :P)?

Comment: I mean that, if you want to show discontinuity in $x$, it suffices to show that there exists a sequence $x_n \to x$ such that $h(x_n) \to h(x)$ doesn't hold. That doesn't mean that you have to be able to write the sequence as specifically as "$x_n = \frac1n$." Btw, in the proof of continuity in $0$, it should be $h$ instead of $f$.

Comment: Ohh yeah, thanks for the $h$. But what kind of sequence would that be? Could you give an example?

Comment: It could be anything, so I can't give an example. We just need to know that a series with these properties exists, we don't have to know what it is exactly.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure I understand. But how would you argue, that the series exists?

Comment: Why did you think that $h$ is not continuous in any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$? Try to go from there.

Comment: Mhh, because it always jumps between negative and positive numbers and it reminds me of the Dirichlet-Function, that was my intention behind my guess..

Comment: Then you could try to apply a similar strategy as for the proof of discontinuity of the dirichlet function

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Mhh, for the dirichlet function I argued, that there is a sequence with limit 0 and one with limit 1, so the function is nowhere continuous, but I'm still not sure, how I could use that for $h(x)$...